# RavenDB - Can I create/query an index, from an application that doesn't share the CLR objects that were persisted?

Tags: ravendb

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13270681/accessing-a-single-ravendb-from-different-applications) post goes some way to answering this question (I'll include the answer later), but I was hoping for some further details.

We have a number of applications that each need to access/manipulate data from Raven in their own way.  Data is only written via the main web application.  Other apps include batch-style tasks, reporting etc.  In an attempt to keep each of these as de-coupled as possible, they are separate solutions.

That being the case, how can I, from the reporting application, create indexes over the existing data, using my locally defined types?

The answer from the linked question states

> As long as the structure of the classes you are deserializing into partially matches the structure of the data, it shouldn't make a difference.
>
> The RavenDB server doesn't care at all what classes you use in the client. You certainly could share a dll, or even share a portable dll if you are targeting a different platform. But you are correct that it is not necessary.
>
> However, you should be aware of the Raven-Clr-Type metadata value. The RavenDB client sets this when storing the original document. It is consumed back by the client to assist with deserialization, but it is not fully enforced

It's the first part of that that I wanted clarification on.  Do the object graphs for the docs on the server and types in my application have to match exactly?  If the Click document on the server is

```
{
  "Visit": {
    "Version": "0",
    "Domain": "www.mydomain.com",
    "Page": "/index",
    "QueryString": "",
    "IPAddress": "127.0.0.1",
    "Guid": "10cb6886-cb5c-46f8-94ed-4b0d45a5e9ca",
    "MetaData": {
      "Version": "1",
      "CreatedDate": "2012-11-09T15:11:03.5669038Z",
      "UpdatedDate": "2012-11-09T15:11:03.5669038Z",
      "DeletedDate": null
    }
  },
  "ResultId": "Results/1",
  "ProductCode": "280",
  "MetaData": {
    "Version": "1",
    "CreatedDate": "2012-11-09T15:14:26.1332596Z",
    "UpdatedDate": "2012-11-09T15:14:26.1332596Z",
    "DeletedDate": null
  }
}
```

Is it possible (and if so, how?), to create a Map index from my application, which defines the Click class as follows?

```
class Click
{
    public Guid Guid {get;set;}
    public int ProductCode {get;set;}
    public DateTime CreatedDate {get;set;}
}
```

Or would my class have to be look like this? (where the custom types are defined as a sub-set of the properties on the document above, with matching property names)

```
class Click
{
    public Visit Visit {get;set;}
    public int ProductCode {get;set;}
    public MetaData MetaData {get;set;}
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Following on from the answer below, here's the code I managed to get working.

**Index**

```
public class Clicks_ByVisitGuidAndProductCode : AbstractIndexCreationTask
{
    public override IndexDefinition CreateIndexDefinition()
    {
        return new IndexDefinition
            {
                Map =
                    "from click in docs.Clicks select new {Guid = click.Visit.Guid, ProductCode = click.ProductCode, CreatedDate = click.MetaData.CreatedDate}",
                TransformResults =
                    "results.Select(click => new {Guid = click.Visit.Guid, ProductCode = click.ProductCode, CreatedDate = click.MetaData.CreatedDate})"
            };
    }
}
```

**Query**

```
var query = _documentSession.Query<ReportClick, Clicks_ByVisitGuidAndProductCode>()
                            .Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOfNow())
                            .Where(x => x.CreatedDate >= start.Date && x.CreatedDate < end.Date);
```

where Click is

```
public class Click
{
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public int ProductCode { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Many thanks @MattJohnson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shape is a partial match, then it will fill in where it can, so your second example would work ok.

You can, however, create an index that projects the results you're showing in your first example.  You would map by whatever you actually were going to filter or sort by, and then you would add a TransformResults section:

```cs
TransformResults = (database, clicks) =>
    from click in clicks
    select new {
        click.Visit.Guid,
        click.ProductCode,
        click.MetaData.CreatedDate
    };
```

When you query this index, it will come out in the shape you specified in the transform.  This is a features called "Live Projections", which you can read more about [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/querying/static-indexes/live-projections).  (You won't need an `.As()` call, just use `.Query<Click, YourIndex>()` and it should work fine.)

Separately - what are you doing with MetaData is extraneous.  Raven keeps metadata separated from the document.  Read more on metadata [here](http://ravendb.net/docs/client-api/advanced/document-metadata).

It looks like you have versioning concerns.  If you are just keeping an audit trail, you should look at Raven's standard [Versioning Bundle](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/bundles/versioning).  If you have temporal effectivity concerns, consider using my new [Temporal Versioning Bundle](https://github.com/mj1856/RavenDB-TemporalVersioning).

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Doesn't the 2nd option mean I still need a matching class in order to define the Map (If I want to use `AbstractIndexCreationTask<Click>`?

As it stands, I've defined the index by overriding `CreateIndexDefinition()` and using strings.

However, querying via client-side LINQ, I get a FormatException('Input string not in the correct format'). The generated Lucene is `{CreatedDate:[20121209000000000 TO NULL] AND CreatedDate:{* TO 20121210000000000}}` and the query is `session.Query<Click, ClickIndex>().Where(x => (x.CreatedDate >= start && x.CreatedDate < end))`.

Comment: If you can create your index in the main application where you have the full class, then you can use c#.  If not, then yes - create the index with strings.  Try `documentStore.DatabaseCommands.PutIndex()` - it's a bit easier than overriding `CreateIndexDefinition()`.  The lucene has extra braces at the begining and end, and the wrong date format.  What version of Raven are you using?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I'll stick with string definitions then.

The server is 960, the version of the client is what Nuget gave me (992).  I grabbed the Lucene directly from VS debugger, I don't know whether that is different to what ends up going over the wire?  Anyhow, please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Got it.  Sorry, I've been working with 2.0 for so long, I forgot 1.0 uses that date format.  The string is valid, the extra braces at start and end are just from visual studio debugger.  I think you must be getting the FormatException from something else.  Can you provide any more code?

Comment: I've just gone back and re-done each of the steps involved in what I've described, and it's now working. I may have had something funky in my index definition, or something else.  Anyhow, it's now working.  I'll update the original post with the full working code.  Many thanks for your help.